# How to retrieve user_type from async storage to allow for conditional rendering on HomePage when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Forgive my question if it's super basic. I'm new to react and react-native.

My app has two types of users, a doctor, and a patient.

Once they are logged in, they will be directed to the homepage. I want to show certain icons to doctors and certain icons to patients once logged in.

In my Homepage, I have the following code for getUser. I'm not sure how to retrieve the user type to use in my conditional rendering. I will show you my code below:

```js
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    storedValue: '',
    storedType: '',
    type: '',
    id: '',
    isLoading: true,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('full_name');
      const storedType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
      const profileImg = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profile_img');
      const type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profileType');
      const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('projectUid');
      //  console.log(storedValue ,storedType, profileImg  ,type , id);
      if (storedValue !== null) {
        this.setState({ storedValue });
      } else {
        // alert('something wrong')
      }
      if (storedType !== null) {
        this.setState({ storedType });
      } else {
        //alert('something wrong')
      }
      if (profileImg !== null) {
        this.setState({ profileImg });
      } else {
        //  alert('something wrong')
      }
      if (type !== null) {
        this.setState({ type });
      } else {
        //  alert('something wrong')
      }
      if (id !== null) {
        this.setState({ id });
      } else {
        //  alert('something wrong')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // alert(error)
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { storedType } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ right: -15 }}>
        {storedType === 'doctor' && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onAdvanceSearchPress} style={styles.AdnanceSearchStyle}>
            <Image source={require('../../Assets/Images/docbutton.png')} style={styles.docImage} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create another file for storage

here is an example

```js
// src/utils/storage.js

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export const setItem = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Storage setItem: ${error}`);
  }
};

export const setJsonItem = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Storage setJsonItem: ${error}`);
  }
};

export const getItem = async (key) => {
  try {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Storage getItem: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

from there you can update you Home component and get your items with

```js
import { getItem } from '../utils/storage';

const userName = await getItem('FULL_NAME');
const userType = await getItem('USER_TYPE');
```

and so on...

From here you can do things like

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser = async () => {
    const userType = await getItem('USER_TYPE');
    this.setState({ userType });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to try to understand what is different from what I did and what you suggested. Because other than storing my data somewhere else, I do see that the ComponentDidMount() that you have is the same as mine. Can you help me understand why mines does not work? I will try your suggestion but I'm just trying to understand where the logic in my code fails.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my new error is "cannot use keyword 'await' outside of an async function"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna mess with `async` and `await` use [sync-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-storage)

On your initial app load

```
function App() {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const init = async () => {
      await SyncStorage.init();
    };

    await init;
  }, []);

  return <Text>My awesome app</Text>;
}
```

And you can Synchronously set or get items

```js
SyncStorage.set('foo', 'bar');
SyncStorage.get('foo'); // 'bar'
```

How I use on my app

```
  if (SyncStorage.get('@sign')) return <User />;
  else return <Auth />;
```